# How to add a framework to a today extension?

Tags: swift, charts, frameworks, today-extension

I have chart in my app, I am using framework Charts for creating it. In my today extension, I need to show dashboard with charts, but I don't understand how to import `Charts.framework` to today extension.

Comment: Hopefully, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390683/adding-framework-and-app-extension-targets-to-ios-app-project-am-i-doing-it-cor) might be useful to your case...

Comment: btw, do you use cocoapods?

Comment: Yes, I use cocoapods. I have done all from you link, but it doesn't help me(